# Interpreting lagged regression model

Tags: regression, stargazer

I've created a regression model which shows the effects of several variables against my outcome (state education expenditure p/pupil: "sqrt_EPP"). I've employed a lagged outcome variable in order to address autocorrelation which I have because my dataset consists of all 50 US states from 1980 to 2009. However, I'm not sure how to interpret it at all. My lagged variable is statistically significant at the 0.01 level but my predictor variable (state policy liberalism: "pollib_median") is not, which I think means that it isn't correlated with sqrt_EPP. I want to say that a one-unit increase in my lagged variable (so one year change) results in a 0.77 increase in sqrt_EPP but I feel that this doesn't say much. I'm not sure how I incorporate my predictor into my interpretation at all. Any help would be greatly appreciated.[image]